# Most Efficient Way of Chunking a Large Iterable in Python for Brute Forcing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, bigdata, brute-force

I am trying to develop a way to address large parallel tasks for bruteforcing a keyspace. I'd like to be able to come up with a way to pass a worker a value in such a way that given a chunk size, that value would tell the work what to output.

Simply Speaking:

given a charset (a-z) and a max legth of 1 (basically a-z) and a chunk size of 5

If I send worker 1 the number 0 then it will take 0-4 of the iterator, a, b, d, e, f) if I send worker 2 the number 1 it will take 5-9 etc. I have that code basically working:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import itertools
maxlen = 5
charset = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

chunksize = 1000
chunkpart = 5


for s in  itertools.islice(itertools.chain.from_iterable((''.join(l) for l in itertools.product(charset, repeat=i))  for i in range(1, maxlen + 1)), chunksize*chunkpart, chunksize*(chunkpart + 1)):
    print s
```

Ok that works great, if I send chunkpart 5 to worker 1 it will do what it needs to do on that chunkpart.

The issue comes into play when I need to get a small chunk (1000 records) but way far into a large set. Let's say the maxlen was 10 and the chunkpart was 50,000,000. It takes a LONG time for Python to get to that point.

So, I think I know WHY this happens, it needs to do quite a bit of math to figure out where to get to in the iterator; what I am wondering, is there a better way for me to do this that shortcuts something? My gut tells me itertools has the answer, my brain says you need to understand itertools better.

Comment: Consider what you've got as base 62 integers. Then you can chunk into blocks of n amount... It also makes it easier to resume/split chunks... It does add some computation time converting to/from a number but conceptually makes things simpler

Comment: It's not that it takes "quite a bit of math", it's that iterables do not support random-access indexing:  to get to, say, the 5 million'th item in the iterable, `islice()` has to generate all 4,999,999 preceding elements first.  That's a nightmare.  @JonClements has the best approach:  do the math yourself.  itertools has no idea how to do it.

Comment: I was experimenting with that, but I hung up on the conversion to the string from the number, I was doing an ASCII lookup, but there were blocks that didn't have the chars I wanted, and that made it so I ended up wasting a loop cycle skipping.  So Base62 ints, I think I am following there, do I just write a simple convert to my charset function as it does it's counting?

Comment: @user3011243 That's about it... You have a function that converts an integer into it's base 62 rep to represent an item as chars... but deal exclusively with ranges of ints.... So you can instantly do `to_key(123456789)` without having to pregenerate products/combinations and ignore them before hand....